# How to Capture Data from UDP Port

Tags: c#, udp

I have purchased IOT Device to tracking production output.I would like to know how to capture data from IOT Device (from UDP Port) using C# Code.The output data format in UDP Port is given below

```
$1001||4001||01||L001||FF||20210507-14:26:45||008984EA#
```

Comment: So....what have you tried so far that didn't work and led you to post here? What dead ends have you reached in researching this problem?

Comment: I can't find proper solution in google

Comment: What did you search for? How to use UDP in C#?

Comment: How to read data from udp port